# How to pairwise compare two ROC curve using sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I have to evaluate the performance of two classification algorithms. I obtain the *False Positive Rate* and the *True Positive Rate*  using the `roc_curve` from sklearn ([here documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html)). I used the following code:

```
fpr = dict()
tpr = dict()
roc_auc = dict()
for i in range(2):
    fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(true_labels, pred_labels)
    roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])
```

I have this information for two classifiers, and now I want to **compare** them. I know that it is possible to use AUC or other metrics, but **I really want to understand the percentage of times a ROC curve is over the other.** For this reason, I would like to compare pairwise points from the two curves.

My first idea was to compare, for each *fpr* element the corresponding *tpr*. Unfortunately, the `fpr` and `tpr` objects have different size, since they are the output of an interpolation step.

Any idea on how to do so? It seems that I cannot say to the `roc_curve` function how many (and which) points I want in the output, in order to make the comparison feasible. It is not mandatory to use sklearn.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "the percentage of times a ROC curve is over the other"?  Is the percentage meant as over the x-axis, the thresholds, something else?

Comment: I mean that (assuming that I have 100k points) I want to know how many times the y-value of Curve1 is higher than Curve2

Comment: Just to be sure: the 100k points are x-values? So you don't care how the thresholds between the two classifiers compare?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is not specific to sklearn but is a scientific method. Using a Monte-Carlo method. Generate 10K points inside a unit square and count the number which is denoted by `c`, of points that is under both ROC curves. `c/10000` is equal to the intersection area of these two curves as the area of a unit square is `1`.

To generate a random point inside a unit square you can use the following code:

```
import random 

x = random.random()
y = random.random()
```

ِyou can check that the point of `(x,y)` is under a curve with the list of `xs` and `ys` by adding `0` to the tail of them and use of the following code:

```
is_under = True
for i in range(1, len(xs)): # 0 is added to the tails of xs and ys
    m = (y[1] - y[0])/(x[1]-x[0])
    if y > m * (x - x[0]) + y[0]:
        is_under = False
        break
```

In the above code, we checked that the given point `(x,y)` should be under any segment of the curve. If it is, at the end of the loop `is_under` must be `True`, and it must be `False` otherwise.

Notice that if you increase the number of points, the precision of the method will be increased.

Comment: I have not any kind of function that defines my curves. Basically each curve is only defined by a subset of points (more or less 5k points in the range 0-1 for both x and y-axis), but these points are never exactly the same (the digit precision of each coordinate is really high). Monte Carlo methods are a good choice, but I don't know how to make the points sampling

Comment: @AndreaM generating a random point inside a unit square is straightforward. Please see the update.

Comment: Monte Carlo methods are a great idea. Anyway, let's consider that my "curves" are defined as follows:
```x_1: [0, 0.01, 0.05, 0.08, ....]```
```x_2: [0, 0.02, 0.04, 0.09, ...]```
And for the y:
```y_1: [0.2, 0.24, 0.26, ...]``` 
```y_2: [0.3, 0.32, 0.35, ...]```
As you can see, the x-values are not the same, so I don't know how to evaluate if one of the generated random points are under both the curves

Comment: what do you mean with ```xs```, ```x``` and ```y```?

Comment: @AndreaM `xs` and `ys` are (`x_1` and `y_1`) or (`x_2` and `y_2`). You need to run this loop for each point and if both of them return true, you can count it as a intersection. `x` and `y` are the position of the random generated point (as mentioned in the post).